# What are the definitive special characters to use at the beginning to invoke the ECHO Windows batch command safely and in the most performant manner?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, special-characters

I've been aware of the technique of using a special character immediately after the ECHO command instead of a space for a very long time. As hardcore scripters will be aware of already, this is done mainly to safely use the ECHO command where the argument to the ECHO command has the possibility of resolving as empty. If the special character technique is not used, the ECHO command would output ECHO ON, in such cases. Additionally, using such a special character has the advantages of changing the parsing behavior to allow using certain special characters in the argument itself, safely, as well as having the added benefit, seemingly, of being more performant when certain special characters are used.

Quite some time ago, I encountered a treatment/post on Stack Exchange or elsewhere on some forum or Q&A site, that extensively analyzed and compared the safety and performance benefits of different special characters. That post indicated that the character I had been using thus far `(`, while being among the best, was not THE best option, IIRC. A different character topped the list, and there were some pros/cons associated with certain special characters.

I've been trying to trace that post recently, but so far have come empty.

I think the information that was available on that post was very valuable and those using SO would find this so as well.

Does anyone have access to the above mentioned information, or is anyone interested in attempting to duplicate the said treatment/analysis?

Command I currently use: `ECHO(Hello, World!`

Web Search keywords tried: `windows batch file script echo safe escape character fast`, and variations thereof.

Expected: A thorough, and preferably an exhaustive treatment of all ASCII special characters. As the list of ASCII characters is limited and well defined, I don't believe this question is subjective as posed. However, if anyone still thinks it's subjective or too broad, they may instead limit answers to picking a single best character found experimentally under the criteria of safety and performance, in a scientific and repeatable manner.

**Note:** This is *not* simply a question about using special characters in batch files/CMD, as most of the other answers coming up seem to be about.

Comment: If you move the "rant" about SO to the end of your post, more people might continue to read down to the actual question - more likely to get an answe

Comment: I don't understand why the question is closed by `opinion based`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion the `echo(` is the best and only choice, because it works in nearly every situation [See #The only problem]. All other variants have some drawbacks.

Some time ago, I tested all possible `echo<character>` variants at [dostips: ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774&start=0#p4554)

I tested different use cases:

1. Can it echo an empty line
2. Can it output any content from a variable
3. Is there a filesystem access or fail the echo when there are specific files in the current directory.

#### 1. Can it echo an empty line

All, but `echo<space>` can output an empty line

#### 2. Can it output any content from a variable

Problematic texts are `/?`, `ON`, `OFF` or `..\..\..\..\windows\system32\calc.exe`

These fail with a simple `/?` or just `?`

```
set "var=/?"  
echo;%var%
echo,%var%  
echo=%var%  
echo %var%  
set "var=?"  
echo/%var%
```

These fail with `..\..\..\..\windows\system32\calc.exe`

```
set "var=..\..\..\..\windows\system32\calc.exe"  
echo\%var%  
echo:%var%  
echo.%var%
```

#### 3. Is there a filesystem access

These variants fails when there exists a corresponding file.

```
echo[  
echo]  
echo+  
echo.
```

### The winner is:

`echo(`

#### The only problem ...

... is the usage as command by delayed or FOR-parameter expansion

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "cmd=echo:"
%cmd% Test1 okay
!cmd! Test2 okay
for /F %%C in ("%cmd%") DO %%C Test3 okay
set "cmd=echo("
%cmd% Test4 okay
!cmd! Test5 fail
for /F %%C in ("%cmd%") DO %%C Test6 fail
```

> Test1 okay
> Test2 okay
> Test3 okay
> Test4 okay
> Der Befehl "echo(" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder konnte nicht gefunden werden.
> Der Befehl "echo(" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder konnte nicht gefunden werden.

Comment: Thank you! That link was exactly what I was looking for. @Compo while the gory details are not included here, the link gets you there.

Comment: In the linked thread, the failure cases are described in this post: https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774&start=30#p67480

Comment: @T3RR0R The link show the problem with `CALL echo /?` but that is irrelevant, because `call <anycommand> /?` always fails, it's not related to ` echo`

Comment: Whilst I appreciate that another site may help to solidify the statement made by jeb, answers should, when possible, be quantifed here, not require the reader to go elsewhere. The answer above essentially tells me the drawbacks of some other characters, and currently appears to deliberately ignore any failures with their own choice. Without that, it risks being opinion based, _(which this question promotes)_, and would have been more appropriate as a comment linking to the other site.

Comment: @Compo I added some explanation to the problem with `echo(`

Comment: Thanks for the additional effort @jeb. _IMO, creating a variable with a value string of five characters, which when typed out uses itself five characters is kind of strange anyhow!_

Comment: @Compo consider the following use case: `if %DEBUG%=true set "cmd=echo(" else set "cmd=REM "'

Comment: @jeb that post also contains examples for the failure cases that occur when expanded with Delayed expansion or if expanded as a For metavariable

Comment: @T3RR0R You are right and the example is even from myself :-)